# Prove that language $X$ is not decidable

Tags: turing-machines

$$X =\{\langle M, w\rangle \mid\text{$M$ has one tape and never modifies portion of the}$$ $$\text{tape that contains the input $w$}\}$$

And my proposition: Let $@$ will be character such that there is no $@$ in alphabet. Let suppose, that $X$ is decidable, so we try reduce $A_{TM}$.
Let $R$ will be machine that decides $X$, and $S$ decides $A_{TM}$
$A_{TM} = \{\langle M, w\rangle|M\ accepts\ w\} $
$S\text{ on input }= \langle M, w\rangle:$

$ \text{(1) We construct TM T:}$

$\text{ (1.1) Simulate $M$ on input $w$}$

$\text{ (1.2) When it accepts write @ on the left-most ceil of tape}$

$\text{(2) Run $R$ on input $\langle T, w\rangle$}$

$\text{(3) Accept when $R$ accepts, and reject when $R$ rejects}$

What about this solution ?

Comment: What is $A_{TM}$? And what is $T$ used for? You construct it and then never mention it again.

Comment: I corrected it.